# Asynchronous action within javascript promise finally block

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am implementing a function that returns a `Promise`. In its implementation, I am calling another function, itself returning a `Promise`, on which I need to transform the result a bit.

Something like this:

```
function myDoStuff(params) {
    return actuallyDoStuff(params).then(
        (result) => { return "myTransformation " + result; }
    );
}
```

Now, I also need to call some cleanup code, whether this succeeds or fails. I could add a `finally` clause to the returned promise, but the problem is: what I need to do in the finally clause is also asynchronous (basically, another function returning a `Promise` again), and I need the returned promise to wait for the finalization to be done before it settles.

It seems I can't return a promise within the `finally` function (at least, it doesn't seem to be mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).

So, do I need to call the finalization from both `then` and `catch`, chaining the promises, or is there a way using a `finally` construct?

Calling finalization in both cases and preserving the error of the `actuallyDoStuff` results in ugly code:

```
function myDoStuff(params) {
    return actuallyDoStuff(params).then((result) => {
        return doFinalization().then(() => {
            return "myTransformation " + result;
        });   
    }, (err) => {
        return doFinalization().then(() => {
            throw err;
        }), () => {
            throw err;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Chain the returned promise from the 2nd function with `then()` for success, `catch()` for errors and another `then()` for your cleanup code.

Comment: If you can call then, catch etc within promise, you ought to be able to call finally as well. :)

Comment: @ponury-kostek Come on, of course finally returns a promise. I mean I can't return a Promise from my implementation of the finally block (the ``onFinally`` function, in the documentation).

Comment: @dim : can you illustrate why you need to wait for doFinalization to complete, before completing your Promise chain ?

Comment: @LeGEC Well, that is how my finalization function is implemented. It calls some ajax stuff, and I need that to be completed before continuing.

Comment: async / await with try / catch ftw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can** return a promise from `finally`, and that will indeed hold up the chain. That promise just can't change the resolution value, and resolution value it returns will be ignored in favor of the original one. (It **can** change a resolution into a rejection, so you have to be careful there.)

So just add onto the chain, if you want to allow cleanup to convert resolution to rejection if cleanup fails:

```
function myDoStuff(params) {
    return actuallyDoStuff(params)
        .then(
            (result) => { return "myTransformation " + result; }
        )
        .finally(cleanup);
}
```

If you want to ignore errors from cleanup, you need to suppress them:

```
function myDoStuff(params) {
    return actuallyDoStuff(params)
        .then(
            (result) => { return "myTransformation " + result; }
        )
        .finally(() => cleanup().catch(() => {}));
}
```

Examples:

```js
// Note this takes only 10ms
function actuallyDoStuff(valueOrError, fail = false) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(fail ? reject : resolve, 10, valueOrError);
  });
}

// Note this takes a full second
function cleanup(fail = false) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(fail ? reject : resolve, 1000, "cleanup done");
  });
}

function myDoStuff(...params) {
    return actuallyDoStuff(...params)
        .then(
            (result) => { return "myTransformation " + result; }
        )
        .finally(cleanup);
}

console.log("start with success");
myDoStuff("success")
  .then(value => console.log("success", value))
  .catch(error => console.log("error", error))
  .finally(() => {
    console.log("Notice how there was a 1,010ms delay, and that the result was from actuallyDoStuff, not cleanup");
    console.log("start with error");
    myDoStuff("error", true)
      .then(value => console.log("success", value))
      .catch(error => console.error("error", error))
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("Notice how there was a 1,010ms delay");
       });
         });
```

---

It's worth noting that now that `async`/`await` is here, you can also do this:

```
async function myDoStuff(params) {
    try {
        const result = await actuallyDoStuff(params);
        return return "myTransformation " + result;
    } finally {
        await cleanup(); // Allows errors from cleanup
    }
}
```

or

```
async function myDoStuff(params) {
    try {
        const result = await actuallyDoStuff(params);
        return "myTransformation " + result;
    } finally {
        await cleanup().catch(() => {}); // Suppresses errors from cleanup
    }
}
```

or with a `try`/`catch` in the `finally` (but it's more verbose):

```
async function myDoStuff(params) {
    try {
        const result = await actuallyDoStuff(params);
        return "myTransformation " + result;
    } finally {
        try {
            await cleanup()
        } catch (e) { // As of ES2019, you could leave the `(e)` off
                      // That's already at Stage 4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Since the MDN specs is incomplete on that, do you have an idea where this is specified? I just realized finally doesn't even seem to be specified at all in the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: @dim - MDN isn't a spec, it's a community-edited documentation site. :-) The actual spec does indeed cover this, though the prose is...difficult to follow: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.prototype.finally If you didn't find it, you were probably looking at one of the snapshot specs from before ES2018 (when `finally` was added). The one I linked to is the "living" spec that incorporates everything at Stage 4 or later (e.g., what will be in the next June snapshot).

Comment: Indeed, I instantly caught a headache. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @dim :-) Yeah, it's...fun... BTW, updated the answer to flag up `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return original result from `actuallyDoStuff` after `doFinalization`

```js
function myDoStuff(params) {
 return actuallyDoStuff(params).then((result) => {
  return doFinalization().then(() => {
   return "myTransformation " + result;
  }).finally(doFinalization);
 });
}

function doFinalization(result) {
 console.log("Finalizing"); // It can be async or not
 return Promise.resolve("finalized").then(() => {
  // return original resolution of actuallyDoStuff
  return result;
 });
}

function actuallyDoStuff(params) {
 console.log("Doing stuff");
 return params ? Promise.resolve("ok") : Promise.reject("failed");
}

myDoStuff(true).then(res => console.log("Result", res)).catch(err => console.error("Error", err));
myDoStuff(false).then(res => console.log("Result", res)).catch(err => console.error("Error", err));
```