# Await inside finally block in an async function doesn't wait

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js script like this (for educational purposes it's entangled, not actual production code):

```
const run = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (async () => {
        let cleanup = () => {
            console.log('inside cleanup');
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                }, 5000);
            });
        };

        try {
            throw new Error('error');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('rejecting')
            reject(err);
        } finally {
            console.log('inside finally')
            await cleanup().then(() => {
                console.log('exiting');
                resolve('done');
            });
        }
    })();
});

run.then((r) => console.log(r));
```

Based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288406/2545680), I would expect Node to wait and not exit until the promise inside `finally` is resolved. However, it seems to exit immediately. What am I missing here?

```
$ node pup
rejecting
inside finally
inside cleanup
D:\pup.js:16
            throw new Error('error');
                  ^
```

I might need to cleanup multiple resources in `finally` in certain order, so I'd need to wait for completion of previous cleanup actions.

Comment: Mixing `await` with `.then()` is not a great idea.

Comment: Using `new Promise` when you already have a promise (i.e. when you aren’t converting a callback API to a Promise API) is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: You do `reject(err);` when catching an error but *also* do `resolve('done');` in the `finally` block. What do you actually expect to happen to the  `run` promise?

Comment: There is such a long list of things wrong here.  Not worth fixing or answering questions about because it's just wrongly written as it's just not the way to use promises or `async/await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node does not wait for any particular promise, it only cares about the event loop. And it does terminate early when there is an unhandled exception anywhere (including unhandled promise rejections). And that is exactly your problem: your code is already `reject()`ing the `run` promise *before* the `finally` block runs, before the promise returned by the `async` function (which you are ignoring) is settled. And since you have not caught the rejection of `run` (e.g. using `run.then(console.log, console.error)`), nodejs exits while the function is still running.

To fix this, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and use

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function run() {
    try {
        throw new Error('error');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('handling error')
        throw err;
    } finally {
        console.log('cleaning up')
        await delay(5000);
        console.log('exiting');
        // return 'done';
    }
}

run().then(console.log);
```

You should avoid `return`ing from a `finally` block as that would override the exception. If you actually meant to handle the error in the `catch` block, do not re-`throw` it:

```
async function run() {
    try {
        throw new Error('error');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('handling error', err.message)
    } finally {
        console.log('cleaning up')
        await delay(5000);
        console.log('exiting');
    }
    return 'done';
}
```

Comment: _before the finally block runs_, interesting, but why do I then see the log statement from inside the `finally`?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi — “before” doesn’t mean “instead of”.

Comment: @Quentin, interesting, so basically `unhandled promise rejection` is what causes the process to not wait for `await` inside the `finally` block, but the block itself still runs? I now understood your comment _By the time you call resolve you’ve already called reject._ in your answer

Comment: No. The `await` does make it wait (after you've `reject`ed the first of the three promises you explicitly create).

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi The process does not care for `await`s or promises all - the `await` only affects the `async` function execution. The process simply runs as long as the event loop keeps going (e.g. `setTimeout`), and it may terminate early if there is an unhandled exception/rejection.

Comment: @Bergi, so since I `reject` the top level `run` promise that the node process cares about when it comes to the process completion, the `reject` results into `unhandled exception` and the process terminates without waiting for `async/await` stuff that was wrapped into the top level promise constructor, correct?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi No, the node process does not care about "*the top level `run` promise*". It cares about unhandled promise rejections *anywhere*. Really if you had simply caught the rejection (`run.then(console.log, console.error)` instead of only `run.then(console.log)`), the process would not have terminated early.

Comment: @Bergi, so that's the crucial part! *It cares about unhandled promise rejections anywher*, indeed worked how I expected when I added the handler `console.error`. Could you please add your last comment to you answer? It will make the answer complete

Answer (score 2):

The bit of the linked answer you appear to refer to is about (a) the promise returned from a function using the `async` keyword when (b) you `await` a promise inside a `try`.

You are doing neither.

You just call the `reject` callback inside `catch`. That’s for a promise that is completely independent of the `async` IIFE.

By the time you call `resolve` you’ve already called `reject`.

Comment: "*the linked answer […] is about […] when (b) you `await` a promise inside a `try`*" - no, it is indeed about using `await` in a `finally` clause. The code in the `try` block does not matter.